# jQuery event handlers inside React Components

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am using React to extend existing jQuery app, which has a lot of jQuery events. Whenever I need to use jQuery event my React Component looks like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

  componentDidMount(){
    jQuery([events]).on('selected', handler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    jQuery([evenst]).off('selected', handler);
  }

  handler(){
    this.setState({...})
  } 

}
```

As far as I understand, using this approach I create **a handler per instance**, which can hit performance. I am trying to figure out how I can create a single handler that would **point to the right instance whenever jQuery event is triggered**.

***Example:*** I have three **div elements** created with jQuery and a React component inside each. So whenever I **click on the div** I need to execute a method of the React Component's **Instance that is inside**.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Skip the jQuery and attach your event handlers in React instead.

Comment: @jmargolisvt could you give an example or link

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: what about events targeted at window?

Comment: Maybe you could try something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pubsub

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks!